# Cardboard Android

Tags: android, sdk, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Is it possible to focus and open up the information just like we do on click using magnet in cardboard android?
Like ray gaze in unity, is there a alternative for android?
I want to do something like the one shown in [chromeexperiments](http://vr.chromeexperiments.com/)

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @MiladYarmohammadi sorry haven't found any solution for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved!

In [treasurehunt](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/sdk-treasurehunt) sample, you can find `isLookingAtObject()` method which detects where user is looking...

And another method called `onNewFrame` which performs some action in each frame...

My solution for our problem is:

in `onNewFrame` method I've added this snippet code:

```
if (isLookingAtObject()) {
        selecting++; // selecting is an integer defined as a field with zero value!
    } else {
        selecting = 0;
    }
    if (selecting == 100) {
        startYourFunction(); // edit it on your own
        selecting = 0;
    }
}
```

So when user gazes 100 frame at object, your function calls and if user's gaze finishes before *selecting* reaches 100, *selecting* will reset to zero.

Hope that this also works for you

Comment: Thanks, i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. (Did small research, (fingers crossed) whether the link shared below  directly answers your question)

- You could check [GazeInputModule.cs](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/blob/master/Cardboard/Scripts/GazeInputModule.cs) from GoogleSamples for
  Cardboard-Unity from Github. As the documentation of that class says:
  *This script provides an implemention of Unity's `BaseInputModule`
  class, so  that Canvas-based UI elements (_uGUI_) can be selected by
  looking at them and  pulling the trigger or touching the screen. 
  This uses the player's gaze and the magnet trigger as a raycast
  generator.*
- Please check some tutorial regarding Google Cardboard Unity [here](http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/11/google-cardboard-unity-tutorial/)
- Please check Google-Samples posted in Github [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity)

Comment: Hi gansai, thankyou for the response. But i need ray gaze functionality in cardboard android, and not in unity. some similar function which does the same logic.

Comment: Hi @pallavi, Could ray-gazing functionality in cardboard android be done using unity plugin for android? (https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/get-started)

Comment: i think it can be done has there is reference for it in [cardboard google](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/reference) Ray Gaze property in **CardboardHead.cs**. so i wanted the same kind of functionality in android just like in unity.

Comment: Good to hear that. :). Just checked code in github,  found the Ray Gaze  property - [github code](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/blob/master/Cardboard/Scripts/CardboardHead.cs)

Comment: good to know that, but i am looking for android and not using unity, so if you get any reference regarding android cardboard, please post it, thanks.

Comment: So, (just to be clear), you mean to say that you want to develop purely using [Google Cardboard SDK](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/) and do not wish to use [Unity Plugin](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/) at all, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90884/discussion-between-gansai-and-pallavi).